# extract word from string after it follows a special character, pandas

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas

I have a column in pandas that is just a string. I want to create a new column that extracts only part of the string with the following format '@example'. I first tried split but didn't seem to help. I'm not sure what kind of string method I should use.

Comment: can you (and you should) provide a sample data together with the expected output from that data.

Comment: I want to take a string (located in a pandas table), like: "this plate of food was really good, thank you @thefoodguy for sharing this with me!" I need to extract only @ thefoodguy from this string and place it in a new column in pandas.